# Why aren't keys being detected?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I have a Pong game and am trying to figure out how to detect a couple of keys. Here is my paddle class:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Paddle extends Rectangle2D.Float{
    public Paddle(int x, int y){
        super.x = x;
        super.y = y;
        super.width = w;
        super.height = h;
    }
}
```

Here is the `PongBall` class:

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class PongBall extends Ellipse2D.Float{
    public PongBall(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        super.x = x;
        super.y = y;
        super.width = w;
        super.height = h;
    }
}
```

Here is the class/area that the paddle and ball will be on:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class PongPlayArea extends JComponent implements KeyListener{

public int width, height;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    PongPlayArea ppa = new PongPlayArea(600, 600);
    Timer t = new Timer(20, e -> {ppa.repaint();});
    t.start();

    frame.add(ppa);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public PongPlayArea(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, width, height));
    g2.fill(getVisibleRect());

    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.draw(new Paddle());
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}
}
```

My problem is that when ever the key is pressed (in this case, the right arrow key) nothing is happening. I don't know what is wrong. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT:
ANSWER:
As suggested by camickr, Instead of use KeyListener, I have decided to use key binding, which is much more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in your event methods and debugging to see if they are even being triggered?

Comment: @Jim Yes, I have, and sadly the method is not even being called.

Comment: What I was kind of getting at is, if your event method isn't even being called, chances are you didn't wire up your event properly.  I think the one answer below pretty much said the same thing.

Comment: You should NOT be using a KeyListener. This question is asked daily. You should be using Key Bindings. You may find more information by looking at the topics under the `Related` heading on the right of this page or you can search the forum for key bindings.

Comment: @camickr, I'll look into it. Thanks.  Is there a particualr reason that KeyListener should not be used though?

Comment: @WyattLowery, check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

Comment: Again, follow @camickr's recommendations. Also, don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your method override.

Comment: I've taken up camikr's recommendation, and it works perfect. Thanks for introducing me to key binding.

Comment: @WyattLowery then I would suggest unselecting your accepted answer and perhaps providing your own answer and accepting that, otherwise it's misleading to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by camickr, key bindings is the way to go. Do not use key listeners.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`.addKeyListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener-java.awt.event.KeyListener-) to register your `KeyListener` implementation.  Call it on the component on which you want to listen for key events.  Probably `this.addKeyListener(this);`.  I would make your KeyListener implementation a separate class.

Comment: I added it to the constructor, still nothing happened.

Comment: Try calling requestFocus() right below where you add the listener.

Comment: The component will only receive key events when it has the keyboard focus. Try requesting it, as ReubenSanders suggests, or click in the component to give it the focus.

Comment: Use Key Bindings. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings to handle `Actions`  for a specific `KeyStroke`.

Comment: @WyattLowery: follow camickr's recommendation, not dsh. While dsh means well, few here have Rob Camick's Swing expertise. Note that Key Bindings is how Swing components themselves detect key strokes, and has greater flexibility and power than KeyListeners. It also allows you to avoid the focus issue.

Comment: @WyattLowery Not sure how this answered the question: 1) you can't click on a JComponent to give it focus. 2) you can't use requestFocus() on a component unless the component is displayed on a visible frame, so the method can't be invoked in the constructur. 3) the proper method to use is requestFocusInWindow(). 4) By default a JComponent isn't focusable so it can't receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better solution is to use `KeyboardFocusManager`. You may have problems (as above) with KeyListeners, because it requres to be focused, you have to register Listener and add methods to your `PongPlayArea` class (which becomes very long) etc. One I had problems similar to your, and the best solution I found was `KeyboardFocusManager`.
To your constructor:

```
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
```

And create class:

```
private class GameDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.getKeyCode() == 82) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Check if it works if you want and tell me is it solved your problems.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Nobody know what "82" means. This is not an advisable solution. The logic will be executed for "all components" on the frame. Yes, in this case it may not matter, but it is not the approach to use. Again read up on `Key Bindings`.